# 'bootstrap' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, scriptmanager

I'm learning asp.net and so I'm trying to build up the project named "Wingtip Toys" from MSDN.

The project is developed on VS 2013 and I have VS 2012. When I try to add Bootstrap per the instruction from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation) I get the error on runtime in browser.

Server Error in '/' Application.

> 'bootstrap' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 'bootstrap' is
> not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.

when I add the `.js` on the master page it shows me to another error:

> The assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'bootstrap.js'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly.

I also add the CSS file to Bundle.config but still the same result. I already have the NuGet package available, like for the `jQuery.js` error, but I'm unable to sort this out yet.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me.
I added this to my BundleConfig.cs file:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("bootstrap", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
        DebugPath = "~/scripts/bootstrap.js",
        LoadSuccessExpression = "bootstrap"
    });
```

Comment: How did you know to add this to your BundleConfig.cs file?

Answer (score 1):

Please go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions.

In Browse, search for: AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap

If your version of bootstrap is higher than AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap first uninstall bootstrap and then install AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

1. go to:

   - Tools

     - NuGet Package Manager

       - Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions...
2. search for Bootstrap.css
3. install it
4. try to run your app